# Ubuntu 16.04 repeats keys without holding down any key

Tags: 16.04, wireless-keyboards

I've got a strange bug on Ubuntu 16.04. I am sort of a new user to Ubuntu so I don't know how to troubleshoot this problem myself and it is very annoying. The problem is that every now and again Ubuntu acts as if I am holding down the "5" key and keeps on repeating the number until I stop it by pressing any other key. That solves the problem until the next time. I am using the [Logitech Wireless K520 keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/wireless-combo-mk520).

What I've tried so far

1. In Settings I've ticked off the "Key presses repeat when key is held down". This solves the problem but I would really love to put it back on.
2. I've increased the delay as well but that did not seem to fix the problem.

Here is a [JSFiddle with my hardware](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dani_ivanov/44bbpeq0/2/embedded/) (if it helps)

If anyone can help out, I would be more than happy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Me too, same key, on 16.04 - never seen it on previous versions. I've been inspecting my MK700/710 keyboard for a sticky 5. I see nothing strange in the syslog at the time of the repeating key. I suspect a bug report needs to be raised. I'll see if I can fight my way through to do so.

Comment: I managed to raise a bug report.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1580732

Comment: Exact same keyboard, exact same issue.

Comment: Man, JSFiddle...? Pastebin is just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I tried turning off "repeat keys". It does stop the endless 5's across the screen, but I still get random single 5 characters.  Losing the ability to repeat arrow keys is a nuisance, but not as bad as the main fault.